# How do I convert text to bitmap in createjs?

Tags: canvas, bitmap, createjs, easeljs

For instance I have this code:

```
var text = new createjs.Text("Hello World", "Bold 10px Arial", "#000000");
```

And I want it to get turned into bitmap.

Comment: Look into cache() -- I will post an example tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [cache()](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_cache) method, which creates an off-screen canvas of the content.

```
var b = text.getBounds();
text.cache(b.x, b.y, b.width, b.height, 2);
```

Here is an example showing cache, as well as exporting the cache to a dataURL, and then making an image with it.
http://jsfiddle.net/0wgwaLr6/

```
var url = text.cacheCanvas.toDataURL();
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are misunderstanding how the objects are rendered with createJS?

Everything (images, texts, animations) is drawn on a `canvas`, which means they don't exist as their individual elements (like text), but rather as a 'drawing'. That also means you can convert it at any time in an image.

You can either do that by right-clicking on the `canvas` and saving the image if you need it only once, or programmatically with:

```
image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

or

```
image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); //larger, higher quality
```